# Cannot create button array in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, button, control-array

This is the code i using, but i not sure why it can be implement via the way i done in window form.

```
        Button[] btnMonday = new Button[20];
        string[] timeslot = { "08:00 AM", "08:30 AM", "09:00 AM", "09:30 AM", "10:00 AM", "10:30 AM", "11:00 AM", "11:30 AM", "12:00 PM", "12:30 PM", "01:00 PM", "01:30 PM", "02:00 PM", "02:30 PM", "03:00 PM", "03:30 PM", "04:00 PM", "04:30 PM", "05:00 PM", "05:30 PM" };

        #region Monday
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            btnMonday[i].SetValue(Height, 38);
            btnMonday[i].SetValue(Width, 256);
            btnMonday[i].SetValue(Content, timeslot[i]);
            btnMonday[i].SetValue(Background, 0xFF, 0xB1, 0xB1, 0xB1);

            // Sets dependency properties
            btnMonday[i].SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
            btnMonday[i].SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i + 1);
            // Adds the dynamically created control to the canvas
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(btnMonday[i]);
        }
```

## update

i still getting error with this portion of code ::

```
 Button[] btnMonday = new Button[20];
            string[] timeslot = { "08:00 AM", "08:30 AM", "09:00 AM", "09:30 AM", "10:00 AM", "10:30 AM", "11:00 AM", "11:30 AM", "12:00 PM", "12:30 PM", "01:00 PM", "01:30 PM", "02:00 PM", "02:30 PM", "03:00 PM", "03:30 PM", "04:00 PM", "04:30 PM", "05:00 PM", "05:30 PM" };

            #region Monday
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                btnMonday[i] = new Button();
                btnMonday[i].SetValue(Height, 38);
                btnMonday[i].SetValue(Width, 256);
                btnMonday[i].SetValue(Content, timeslot[i]);

                // Sets dependency properties
                btnMonday[i].SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
                btnMonday[i].SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i + 1);
                // Adds the dynamically created control to the canvas
                LayoutRoot.Children.Add(btnMonday[i]);
            }
```

is there any possibility of syntac error ?? and may i know how to set value of background to button ?? it seem not work well with the previous style of define background color.The error i get ::

```
Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'System.Windows.DependencyProperty'
```

and

```
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty, object)' has some invalid arguments
```

for this few line

```
        btnMonday[i].SetValue(Height, 38);
        btnMonday[i].SetValue(Width, 256);
        btnMonday[i].SetValue(Content, timeslot[i]);
        btnMonday[i].SetValue(Background, 0xFF, 0xB1, 0xB1, 0xB1);
```

Comment: How about you tell us THE ERROR!

Comment: @Gabe, please check comment in answer of ojlovecd

Comment: No, when asking the question place all relevant information in the question.

Comment: @Gabe, Sorry and will be better of information details with error details in next question =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you insist using SetValue method, try this:

```
        btnMonday[i].SetValue(Button.WidthProperty, 38);
        btnMonday[i].SetValue(Button.HeightProperty, 256);
        btnMonday[i].SetValue(Button.ContentProperty, timeslot[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Button[] btnMonday = new Button[20];
    string[] timeslot = { "08:00 AM", "08:30 AM", "09:00 AM", "09:30 AM", "10:00 AM", "10:30 AM", "11:00 AM", "11:30 AM", "12:00 PM", "12:30 PM", "01:00 PM", "01:30 PM", "02:00 PM", "02:30 PM", "03:00 PM", "03:30 PM", "04:00 PM", "04:30 PM", "05:00 PM", "05:30 PM" };

    #region Monday
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        btnMonday[i] = new Button();
        btnMonday[i].Height = 38;
        btnMonday[i].Width = 256;
        btnMonday[i].Content = timeslot[i];

        // Sets dependency properties
        Grid.SetColumn(btnMonday[i], 0);
        Grid.SetRow(btnMonday[i], i + 1);
        // Adds the dynamically created control to the canvas
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(btnMonday[i]);
    }
```

try this

Comment: i getting this error @.@ Error - The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty, object)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: the problem is come from this three line 
                btnMonday[i].SetValue(Height, 38);
                btnMonday[i].SetValue(Width, 256);
                btnMonday[i].SetValue(Content, timeslot[i]);

Comment: it's okay =D Never worry about that and thx for helping hand ^^

Answer (score 1):

> I think it's gotta get null reference error.
>
> You first declare and allocate to Button array.
>
> But each button needs allocation.
>
> btnMonday[i] = new Button();

Answer (score 1):

```
        Button[] btnMonday = new Button[20];
        string[] timeslot = { "08:00 AM", "08:30 AM", "09:00 AM", "09:30 AM", "10:00 AM", "10:30 AM", "11:00 AM", "11:30 AM", "12:00 PM", "12:30 PM", "01:00 PM", "01:30 PM", "02:00 PM", "02:30 PM", "03:00 PM", "03:30 PM", "04:00 PM", "04:30 PM", "05:00 PM", "05:30 PM" };

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            btnMonday[i] = new Button();
            btnMonday[i].Height = 38;
            btnMonday[i].Width = 256;
            btnMonday[i].Content = timeslot[i];
            btnMonday[i].Margin = new Thickness(0, i * 68, 0, 0);

            // Sets dependency properties
            btnMonday[i].SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
            btnMonday[i].SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i + 1);

            // Adds the dynamically created control to the canvas
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(btnMonday[i]);
        }
```

> I don't understand your question totally, but your code dosen't compile. As above, I fixed it properly.